Android - how to fix java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: Europe/Kyiv
I'm encountering an issue with timezones in my Android application (minSdkVersion = 26). I receive a list of time zones from a server, which includes "Europe/Kyiv". However, when I try to convert it to a ZoneId using ZoneId.of("Europe/Kyiv"), I get the following error:
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: Europe/Kyiv
I've read online that the IANA time zone identifier for Kyiv was updated from "Europe/Kiev" to "Europe/Kyiv" in late 2022.
My question is, what specific updates do I need to make to my project to successfully use ZoneId.of("Europe/Kyiv")?
I updated minSdk to 26, and it didn't help.
Also, I have tried updating the Gradle JDK to 18+ and it doesn't work.

And if you use  "Europe/Kiev" ?

If I use "Europe/Kiev" everything works fine, but I'm supposed to use the newer version that server delivers, and that's "Europe/Kyiv".

Just use Kyiv and when you have an exception use Kiev.

I can do that, but this is not the only zone that has changed, there are more and there will be more.
I'm guessing this has to do with java version, but I cannot get the updated timezones list even when I change the version of java in my project.

Timezone updates are done either by Google or the OEM/ODM: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time/time-zone-policy-recommendations and more specifically: https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/timezone-rules#timezone-apex You should identify how you are testing (emulator/device with make/model/OS version)

@MorrisonChang thank you so much! This is what I needed to see.
I was running my app on various emulators and api versions and got different lists of availableTimezoneIds(), but I couldn't get the new ones. When I run it on real device with android 13 phone - its all good and updated.

@MorrisonChang Can we then say that the problem is in the AS emulators, that the emulators are not updated?

Correct. My guess/expectation is that the emulator is a snapshot of the AOSP code at the time when the version was released. So any tzdata updates aren't applied.

You saved my day! Thank you so muuuuuuch! You can write your comment as an answer if you want; I find it very helpful.

Time zone data (tzdata) updates are done by either Google or the OEM/ODM of the device.
The Android Open Source Project has documentation on Android's time zone policy:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time/time-zone-policy-recommendations
and specifically on how to update time zone files:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/timezone-rules
Based on the comment thread, emulators appear not to be updated with any recent tzdata info, so most likely emulator Android OS is a snapshot of the AOSP at the time of release of a particular version.
Should you need to get updated tzdata, perhaps on older no longer supported devices, you'll need to use a third-party library. Based on the comment in this question Update Android tzdata files, the library: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android may satisfy that need for getting tzdata changes but will require updating the library and your app as required, i.e. with some frequency.
An alternate time library that has tzdata updates is ThreeTenABP but will still require the developer to use the most recent library which has time zone changes.
